# Get latest .NET framework directory

Tags: c#, .net, clr4.0

How can I get the latest .NET CLR Install location ?

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory() is returning the 2.0* location even when the 4.0* is installed.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running within the 4.0 environment?

Comment: I am not running 4.0 environment, but I want install location of 4.0

Comment: Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375860/getting-the-net-framework-directory-path

Answer (score 2):

GetRuntimeDirectory() returns the runtime directory of the current running CLR, which if you're getting the 2.0 path means you're not *running* 4.0 when this code runs, even if it is installed.

Not sure what you're trying to do, but have a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx. Check the InstallPath value under the listed registry keys to get the root path of the framework for a given version.