# How do I get the paths of the directories where .NET reference assemblies are stored, without hardcoding?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Does C# (or Windows) provide a way of getting the location of the directory that contains the .NET reference assemblies for a given version of .NET? On my machine, they are located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v###\
```

Where `###` is any of 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, or 4.6.1. These directories contains mscorlib and some `System` assemblies, and the v4.5+ ones also have some more `System` assemblies in the Facades\ subdirectory.

Is there a better way of obtaining the path of these directories than hardcoding it? (Or, alternatively, is Microsoft committed to keeping the reference assemblies in the same place so that hardcoding it won't break?)

(Context: I'm using Roslyn to compile a project, and it isn't picking up on any of the assemblies referenced in my csproj, framework or otherwise - so I'm loading them manually as metadata references instead. The directory I identified above is where MSBuild is getting the assemblies from when it runs `csc`, so I figure I should get the assemblies from there too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToDotNetFrameworkReferenceAssemblies`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.toollocationhelper.getpathtodotnetframeworkreferenceassemblies.aspx) method from Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core:

```
foreach (TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion version in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion)))
{
    string location = ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToDotNetFrameworkReferenceAssemblies(version);
    Console.WriteLine($"{version}: {location}");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[GetPathToDotNetFrameworkReferenceAssemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.toollocationhelper.getpathtodotnetframeworkreferenceassemblies.aspx) returns "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\version\".

```
ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToDotNetFrameworkReferenceAssemblies(TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion.VersionLatest);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check Microsoft's MSBuild source code at GitHub, you can read `FrameworkLocationHelper.GetPathToDotNetFrameworkReferenceAssemblies` to understand the logic.

Answer (score -1):

[Getting the .NET Framework directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375860/getting-the-net-framework-directory-path):

> The path to the installation directory of the CLR active for the
>   current .NET application can be obtained by using the following
>   method:
>
> `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory()`

Comment: On my machine, that returns `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ `. I suspect these are _probably_ good enough for Roslyn to compile my stuff correctly, but I would appreciate additional information on whether the assemblies in that directory are the same ones (or equivalent to) the ones available in the directory I mentioned in my question.